# SQL: if OBJECT_ID is not null alter table drop constraint VS if exists alter table drop constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out if these two methods used to check the existence of and then drop a constraint are exactly the same or if each gives some sort of difference in result. Code below:

Method 1:

```
if OBJECT_ID('fk_Copy_Item', 'F') is not null
    alter table Rentals.Copy
    drop constraint fk_Copy_Item;
go
```

Method 2:

```
if exists 
(
    select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'Rentals'
    and CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'fk_Copy_Item'
    and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'foreign key'
)
alter table Rentals.Copy
    drop constraint fk_Copy_Item;
go
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your first case, best make sure `fk_Copy_Item` is a constraint on `Rentals.Copy` otherwise I would anticipate an error to be thrown.

Comment: Right, but otherwise these statements are executing the same result? In my classmate's script, both of these statements are included which is why I am confused.

Comment: You might want to take a peek at this article. Looks closely at the section about "non standard foreign keys". https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. The `OBJECT_ID()` function queries against the `sys.objects` table ([MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql)) and the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` is just a view against the same:

```
CREATE VIEW INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
AS
    SELECT DB_NAME()                AS CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,
           SCHEMA_NAME(c.schema_id) AS CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
           c.NAME                   AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
           DB_NAME()                AS TABLE_CATALOG,
           SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
           t.NAME                   AS TABLE_NAME,
           CASE c.type
             WHEN 'C ' THEN 'CHECK'
             WHEN 'UQ' THEN 'UNIQUE'
             WHEN 'PK' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
             WHEN 'F ' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
           END                      AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
           'NO'                     AS IS_DEFERRABLE,
           'NO'                     AS INITIALLY_DEFERRED
      FROM sys.objects c
           LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.parent_object_id
     WHERE c.type IN ('C', 'UQ', 'PK', 'F')
```